# Selected value disable in @Html.Dropdownlist in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am developing an ASP.NET Core project. I am using `IEnumerable` modal. I need to disable selected value. I don't have any idea about how to do that.

```
<td> 
@Html.DropDownList("ProductNames", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.ProductNames, "Select Product", new { id = "productnames", @class = "form-control", @onchange = "GetAmount(this)", @onclick = "GetTrId(this)" })
</td>
```

Comment: You can not disable value, you can only disable a user control

Comment: Can i do it using jQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to disable selected value.

If you'd like to [disable the default selected option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.rendering.selectlistitem?view=aspnetcore-5.0#properties), you can try the following code snippet:

```
 @Html.DropDownList("ProductNames", ((IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.ProductNames).Select(s=> { if (s.Selected) { s.Disabled = true; }; return s; }).ToList(), "Select Product", new { id = "productnames", @class = "form-control", @onchange = "GetAmount(this)", @onclick = "GetTrId(this)" })
```

***Update:***

> I need to disable the "Select product" Word.

You can use the following code snippet to disable that option.

```
$(function () {
    $("select[id='productnames'] option:first-child").attr("disabled", "disabled");
})
```

Comment: I am sorry. I have tried this. But still It doesn't work. I need to disable the "Select product" Word. still i can click on it

Comment: `I need to disable the "Select product" Word` Hi @Chaam, you can try the code in my new update.